# Cross compiled host qmake could not be added after copied to another computer

Tags: qt, cross-compiling

I cross compiled Qt 5.12.2 for raspberry pi successfully according to https://mechatronicsblog.com/cross-compile-and-deploy-qt-5-12-for-raspberry-pi/, a "qt5" folder for host and "qt5pi" for rpi were generated, and I could add the qmake inside "qt5/bin" to Qt Creator, and transfer "qt5pi" to rpi, then cross compiled a simple program and deployed on rpi, everything was fine. I was using Kubuntu 18.10 64bit, and for toolchain I tried were the one in https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools as most tutorials suggested, and gcc-linaro-6.3.1 toolchain, both succeeded.

I have another virtual machine with ubuntu 16.04 64bit on another computer, which I'd also like to use for cross compiling for the same rpi. I did as follows:

1. I made another "sysroot" the same way as the tutorial suggested, from rpi to virtual machine, using rsync, which should be identical to the one in Kubuntu.
2. Then I also transferred the newly compiled "qt5pi" folder from rpi to virtual machine using rsync.
3. Then I transferred "qt5" folder from Kubuntu to virtual machine, also using rsync.

Then when I tried to add qmake in the transferred "qt5/bin" to Qt Creator in virtual machine, it popped an error:"The qmake executable /home/v/raspi/qt5/bin/qmake could not be added." But in Kubuntu the qmake worked fine.

It happened to both toolchains I've tried, succeeded on original host but failed when copied to another. And I did clear everything up, both host and rpi, before changing toolchains. So I don't think it's with the toolchains.

My Kubuntu and virtual machine ubuntu environments are not so different, my other programs compiled in one of them can run normally in the other.
What might caused the problem? Or is there any way to transfer the cross compile environment between host computers? Thanks!

Comment: Is your toolchain relocatable ?

Comment: @Scab I think so. I used pre-compiled binaries. For the git repo ones I simply downloaded from git, and the linaro 6.3 I downloaded a compressed file and extracted things out. I didn't compile the toolchains.

Comment: First, instead of a copy, i would suggest you repeat the same procedure to install your toolchain on the new host and see if that works.

Comment: Annoyingly, a number of paths get "hard coded" into qmake when built. Mostly about where the Qt build itself is located, and also where the sysroot is (and maybe other things). (You can see a few, but hardly all, of those when viewing the "details" of a Qt install in QtCreator kit setup.) So you really need to have things pretty identical (not just "not so different") in terms of those paths. In theory it should work though. The "could not be added" error message is also annoyingly vague. :-/  There might be a log somewhere with more details.

Comment: @Scab The procedure is the same. Thank you both, I'll look further into it, hope I could find a log.